# How to get ReflectionObject object from ReflectionProperty in PHP

Tags: php, reflection

I have a `ReflectionProperty` object using the following code:

```
$service = new \ReflectionClass($this);
$properties = $service->getProperties();
$property = $properties[0];
```

I want to get the `ReflectionObject` object from the `$property` variable to get some extra information about the property (like what is its class and which classes is its class inherited from). How can I achieve this?

e.g.

```
class A {
   /**
   * @var \Utils\WebService
   */
   public $prop;
}
```

now, I get the ReflectionClass (which actually refers to 'A') and I need to get the ReflectionClass/ReflectionObject for the `$prop` property. I need to later check what is the type of `$prop` and what supertypes it extends.

Thanks

Comment: Probably best to start from the manual

Comment: I did, couldnt find any direct method like getReflectionObject in the ReflectionProperty class...

Comment: Check out the [ReflectionProperty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) portion of the manual.  The `ReflectionObject` is an extension of the `ReflectionClass`, which you obtain in the first line of your code.  But the `ReflectionProperty` class may have the methods you need to get the data you are after.

Comment: "the methods" is exactly what I am looking for. ATM, I cant find anything helpful in the ReflectionProperty Class that could help me in finding what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

```
class WebCrawler {
}
class WebService extends WebCrawler {
}


class A {
   /**
   * @var \WebService
   */
   public $prop;

   public $variable = 'hello';

   function __construct()
   {
        $this->prop = new WebService();
   }

}



// reflection
$obj = new A();
$reflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($obj);



// get all public and protected properties
$properties = $reflectionObject->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
$properties = \array_merge($properties, $reflectionObject->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED));
\var_dump($properties);


// create the array similar to what you asked for
$data = [];
foreach ($properties as $property) {
   $name = $property->name;
   $data[$name] = $obj->{$name};
}
\var_dump($data);



// get info which class was inherited to the class defined in A::prop property
$reflectedObjectFromProperty = new \ReflectionObject($data['prop']);
\var_dump($reflectedObjectFromProperty->getParentClass());
```